# How to specify Oracle database schema name in Sqoop import command

Tags: oracle, sqoop

I have an oracle schema/user U1 (password P1) which contains table T1.
There is another oracle schema/user U2 (password P2) which has read permission on table U1.T1.

How can I import T1 using credentials U2/P2. The following command doesn't seem to work.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe --username U2 --password P2 -m 1 --table U1.T1
```

Logs on running with --verbose flag

```
16/10/19 20:52:23 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: Using column names query: SELECT t.* FROM T1 t WHERE 1=0
16/10/19 20:52:23 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM T1 t WHERE 1=0
16/10/19 20:52:23 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: Creating a new connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe, using username:U2
16/10/19 20:52:23 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.
16/10/19 20:52:24 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
16/10/19 20:52:24 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Using fetchSize for next query: 1000
16/10/19 20:52:24 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM TABLE_NAME t WHERE 1=0
16/10/19 20:52:24 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column xxxxxxxxxx of type [2, 19, 0]
16/10/19 20:52:24 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column xxxxxxxxxxxxx of type [12, 36, 0]
16/10/19 20:52:24 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column xxxxxxxxxxxxx of type [-9, 512, 0]
....
16/10/19 20:52:24 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Caching released connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe/U2
16/10/19 20:52:24 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: There is no column found in the target table T1. Please ensure that your table name is correct.
```

Comment: and you able to do it using U1/P1?

Comment: Yes, it's working with `--username U1 --password P1 --table T1`

Comment: can you please share error logs after adding `-verbose` _(to check extended logs)_ in the end of the query?

Comment: In the above query - U2 and U1, T1 are in the upper case right?

Comment: Can you access U1.T1 using U2 in any SQL tool ? If not then I think you may need to create a synonym for this and then access it from sqoop.

Comment: If user U2 doesn't have insert permission (only read) on U1.T1 then it won't be able to insert into U1.T1

Comment: @devツ Edited the question to include logs.
Yes, case was fine.

Comment: @Amit Yes, I can access the table from SQL Developer by logging in an U2/P2. Both `select from T` and 'select from U1.T` are working. Actually, I have a trigger which sets the default schema to U1 whenever U2 logs in.

Comment: @GaryMyers Here, scoop is reading from Oracle DB and writing to Hadoop. So, write permissions are not required for U2 on T1.

Comment: Can you try: 
    `sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe --username U2 --password P2 -m 1 --table T1 -- --schema U1` ?

Comment: @devツ Ran it. Didn't work.
In fact, replacing U1 with some random value also gave the same error.

`Found column xxxxxxxxxxxxx of type [-9, 512, 0]
....
There is no column found in the target table T1.`

Comment: In the above query - U2 and U1, T1 are in the upper case right?  // @devツ This was the problem. U1 is actually something like User1. The user was created using SQL query: `create user User1 identified by password;` There were both upper case and lower case letters in the schema name. Using `--table USER1.T1` instead of `--table User1.T1` worked. Thanks.

Comment: @KB7 that's what I am talking about..:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the case-sensitivity of Table name and Username.

As per sqoop [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_oracle_case_sensitive_catalog_query_errors),

> 1. Specify the user name, which Sqoop is connecting as, in upper case (unless it was created with mixed/lower case within quotes).
> 2. Specify the table name, which you are working with, in upper case (unless it was created with mixed/lower case within quotes).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use something like this `sqoop import -–connect jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@localhost:1521:xe`

Comment: Tried with the following versions. Neither of them worked.
`sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:U2/P2@//localhost:1521/xe --username U2 --password P2 -m 1 --table T1 --verbose`
`sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:U2/P2@//localhost:1521/xe --username U2 --password P2 -m 1 --table U1.T1 --verbose`